# "All results" option for easy-autocomplete search Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add "All results" option to my dropdown search. I limited my search to 5 records:

```
# search_controller.rb
def search
  @catalogs = Catalog.ransack(name_cont: params[:q]).result(distinct: true)
  @products = Product.ransack(name_cont: params[:q]).result(distinct: true)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.json {
      @catalogs = @catalogs.limit(5)
      @products = @products.limit(5)
    }
  end
end
```

And now I want to add an extra option if there are more than 5 results (no matter if it catalogs or products, just an extra option on top of all results). Here is my `easy-autocomplete` setup:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $input = $("[data-behavior='autocomplete']");

  var options = {
    getValue: "name",
    url: function(phrase) {
      return "/search.json?q=" + phrase;
    },
    categories: [
      { listLocation: "catalogs", header: "<strong>Catalogs</strong>" },
      { listLocation: "products", header: "<strong>Products</strong>" }
    ],
    list: {
      onChooseEvent: function() {
        var url = $input.getSelectedItemData().url;
        console.log(url);
        $input.val("");
        window.location.href = url;
      }
    }
  };

  $input.easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

I tried to google because it seems very obvious but I haven't found anything. Read all of the `easy-autocomplete` documentation but still have this problem. Thank you for your help and time!

**UPDATE**

Read `easy-autocomplete` documentation again and found `onLoadEvent` under `Events`. Simplified solution:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // code ...
      onLoadEvent: function() {
        $('.easy-autocomplete-container ul').append("<li>Show all</li>");
      }
  // code ...
  };

  $input.easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```